# Database row wrong ID

Tags: android, database, toast

I Have a FavoriteList.Class and there I have a listview where I'm filling data from the local database. But there is a problem at onClickItem from list is showing the same ID all the time.

Let's say I have item A--> Name: John , ID:10 
and Item B --> Name: Poul , ID: 25
and so on.

Everytime I click on the item in list it showing me ID 10, in toast message, what could the problem can be?

```
public class FavoriteList extends ListActivity {

 public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
 private ListView fortrListView;
 private CursorAdapter conAdapter;
 String TAG = "Favorite Test :  ";


 DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(FavoriteList.this);

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fortrListView=getListView();
    fortrListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewFotrukneListener);

    String[] from = new String[] { "location_name", "location_id" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.FavoriteTextView , R.id.location_id_favotire_saver };
    conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(FavoriteList.this, R.layout.fortrukne_list, null, from, to);
    // set adapter
    setListAdapter(conAdapter); 



    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    //gemme på sharedprefences
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean firstrun = prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true);

   // bruges til at forklare hvordan man tilføjer manuelt...
    if (firstrun) {
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
          editor.putBoolean("firstrun", false);
          if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
              editor.apply();
            } else {
                editor.commit();
            }

          // alert
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setMessage("For at tilføje en genbrugsplads, gå ind i  "+"Nærmeste"+" vælg en genbrugsplads og bruge menuen til at tilføje!")
                 .setCancelable(false)
                 .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                          //do things
                     }
                 });
          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show();

        }
    // gem staten
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .edit()
        .putBoolean("firstrun", false)
        .commit();
    }

// onResume Metoden.n
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
   super.onResume();  
   new GetFavorite().execute((Object[]) null);
 } 

// onStop metoden
@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
   Cursor cursor = conAdapter.getCursor();

   if (cursor != null) 
      cursor.deactivate();

   conAdapter.changeCursor(null);
   super.onStop();
}    

//A-syncTask til vise hele objekter fra DB.
private class GetFavorite extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> 
{
   @Override
   protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
   {
      dbConnector.open();
      return dbConnector.getAllFavorite(); 
   } 

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
   {
      conAdapter.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
      dbConnector.close();
   } 
} 

// enkelt item bliver valgt og bliver sendt til en anden activity   
OnItemClickListener viewFotrukneListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
{
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
    {         


       Intent in = new Intent(FavoriteList.this, ShowPlace.class);
       in.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);


       TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.location_id_favotire_saver);
       String genus = tv.getText().toString();

       Log.d(TAG, "this is value :" +genus);
       Log.d(TAG, "this is value :" +ROW_ID);

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this is the value: " + genus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       //startActivity(in);
       //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.right_to_left);
    }
 };    

 //viser xml når man trykke
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.stock_item_menu, menu);
 }

 //menu bliver kaldt
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.remove_item:
  try{
        dbConnector.deletePlace(conAdapter.getItemId(info.position));           
        }
  finally
  {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Slettet",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
        return true;
    default:

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you need to use the position argument, i.e., `arg2`

Comment: I dont want the position in list, I want the "location_id" of that item in the list.

Comment: use a customAdapter to your listView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** 
Well, I solved it this way:

```
Cursor theCursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)((ListView)fortrListView).getAdapter()).getCursor();
String selection = theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex("location_id"));
```

added to same class, in onItemClick.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)  {         
arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.

Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

Parameters

parent:

The AdapterView where the click happened.

view:

The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)

position:

The position of the view in the adapter.

id

The row id of the item that was clicked.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html